Adopt constraint formulation
I have this constraint which ensures that there are at least $F$ consecutive days off. F.e. for $F=2$, an 1-0-1 is prevented.
$$1+y_{it}\ge y_{i(t-1)}+y_{ik}~\forall i\in I, t\in\left\{ 2,\ldots,T- {F}+1 \right\}, k\in \left\{ t+1,\ldots,t+{F}-1 \right\}$$
I also have two constraints that ensures a minimum ($W$)/maximum ($A$) number of consecutive work days. Is it possible to change my first constraint to a work on, using a summation as in the second constraints?
$$\sum_{j=t}^{t+A}y_{ij}\le A~\forall i\in I,t\in \{1,\ldots,T  - A\}$$
$$\sum_{j=t+1}^{t+W}y_{ij}\ge {W}\cdot(y_{i(t+1)}-y_{it}\forall i\in I, t\in \{1, \ldots, \mid T \mid - {W}\}$$
$x_{ijt}$ and $y_{it}$ are binary variables. $x_{ijt}$ indicates a shift assignment, $y_{it}$ whether a worker works on a day or not. For this
$$\sum_{j\in J} x_{ijt}=y_{it}\forall i\in I, t\in T$$ holds.
$I$ is the set of worker, $J$ of the shifts and $T$ the days.

Did you mean to say that $A$ is the maximum number of consecutive work days?

Your first constraint says that if worker $i$ works on day $t-1$ and also on any day from $t+1$ ot $t+F-1$ then they must also work on day $t.$ How does that ensure any days off?

@prubin Sorry, I misstated the question. I just updated it.

Your second constraint says that a worker cannot work $A+1$ consecutive days. How does that translate to ensuring a minimum number of consecutive work days?

It does not. I just wanted to provide an example, on how the new constraint should kind of look like. I kind of want to utilize a sum--formulation, rather than using another index with another $\forall$ approach.

Please edit your question to clarify the rules, preferably expressed as logical propositions.  You also mention a binary variable $x$ with no indices and no expressed relationship to $y$.

In other words, you want to formulate a length $T$ string of 0s and 1s with each run of 0s having length at least $F$ and each run of 1s having length in $[W,A]$?

Yes, that's correct

See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11478/generalize-working-days-constraints, especially the link to Erwin Kalvelagen's blog post.

Maybe try something like:
$$\sum_{j=t}^{t+F-1}(1-y_{ij})\geq F\cdot (y_{i(t-1)}-y_{it})\quad \forall i\in I, t\in \{2,\ldots,T-F+1\}$$.

This does not prevent $y\equiv1$ (working every day).

If the OP also has a constraint which places an upper bound on consecutive working days?!

According to the comments, the OP's second constraint is not part of the problem but is instead is an example of the form of constraint he wants (an aggregation like yours).

I indeed have both the second from the OP aswell as an upper limit in my model. Would the proposed answer work in this case?

@RobPratt I updated the OP. Does mingabua's answer work in this case?
